# Postgres SQL Query sum + count in one query

Tags: postgresql

I need help to get an result.

| perscarcountoffset | person |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |

I need a Total from a count of the lines where is person 1 + sum of the cell perscarcountoffset

```
select SUM((select sum(perscarcountoffset) from table where  person = 1) + (select count(*) from table where person = 1)) from table where person = 1;
```

Thanks for any idea.

Try to create a query in postgresql. This works but it gives me 4 as result. But it must be only 2.

Comment: Can you show input tables, current output and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

This returns 4 because you're actually computing

```
(select sum(perscarcountoffset) from table where  person = 1) + (select count(*) from table where person = 1)
```

for each row in `table` (where `person = 1`), then summing that. So you're getting 2+2.
This is because anything outside of the aggregation method (i.e. the outer `SUM()` here) is per-row, and the inner sub-selects returns 2 for both rows.

---

The query you want doesn't need to be this complicated, this should do:

```
SELECT SUM(perscarcountoffset) + COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE person = 1;
```